# How to properly type optional arguments in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, optional-parameters

I am trying to write a function that recursively determines the amount of steps needed to resolve the collatz conjecture. I want the function input to be just the starting input number for the series, with an additional counter variable to be added in the first iteration. The JS equivalent would look like:

```js
const collatz = (v, count) => {
  if (!count) return collatz(v,0)
  if (v === 1) return count
  if (v % 2 === 0) return collatz(v/2, count + 1)
  return collatz(v*3+1, count + 1)
}
```

My Haskell code:

```hs
module CollatzConjecture (collatz) where
collatz :: Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
collatz v () = collatz v 0
collatz 1 count = Just count
collatz v count 
  | even v = collatz (div v 2) next
  | otherwise = collatz (v * 3 + 1) next
  where next = count + 1
```

But the compiler complains

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Integer’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected type: Maybe Integer
        Actual type: Maybe (Maybe Integer)
    • In the expression: Just count
      In an equation for ‘collatz’: collatz 1 count = Just count
  |
4 | collatz 1 count = Just count
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is the error in my thinking?

Comment: `count` has a `Maybe Integer` type, so you just write `collatz 1 count = count`.

Comment: `next` should `(1+) <$> count`.

Comment: Thanks for providing a proper type signature. Well, the second argument of `collatz` is in no way *optional*. Syntactically at least it is a *mandatory* argument, of type `Maybe Integer`.  You want to have a clause like `collatz v Nothing = collatz v (Just 0)`. Note that in Haskell `()` is a separate type, with only one possible value,`()`. It is in no way a substitute for `Nothing`.

Comment: In no way? `Maybe a` is isomorphic to the sum of the unit type `()` and an arbitrary type `a`.

Comment: can't write `()` instead of `Nothing`. that's what "a substitute for ..." means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't pollute your function's public API with an extra parameter used only for an implementation detail. Instead, have your public 1-argument function delegate to a private 2-argument function. Often an internal function like this is named `go`, if you can't think of a better name.

```
collatz :: Integer -> Integer
collatz = go 0
  where go count 1 = count
        go count v | even v = next $ div v 2
                   | otherwise = next $ v * 3 + 1
          where next = go $ count + 1
```

I've also made some other improvements:

1. There's no reason to return a `Maybe Integer` when you never return `Nothing`.
2. I swapped the parameter order (`count` first) to make partial application of `go` and `next` more convenient.
3. Instead of defining your helper variable `next` as an integer, I've defined it as a partial application of `go`, so that your two cases only have to repeat `next`, rather than `go (...) next`.

The function as a whole would also be much simpler if you didn't do the counting yourself at all. I don't suggest this immediately, since it's fairly unrecognizable compared to your initial attempt, but an experienced Haskeller would write this more like:

```
collatz :: Integer -> Int
collatz = length . takeWhile (/= 1) . iterate step
  where step n | even n = n `div` 2
               | otherwise = 3 * n + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The error in your thinking is that `Maybe` is not a keyword, nor is it some kind of a hint to a compiler. It is a type constructor. `Maybe Integer` is a concrete, specific data type. It is used to *represent* the general *concept* of optionality, but by *concrete values* (of this type).

Each value in Haskell has *one* type. It can't be either `Int` or `()`. Haskell's sum types are [*tagged* unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

A type is a type -- *one* type. Values of type `Maybe Int` are written either `Just i` (where `i :: Int`, i.e. `i` has type `Int`) or `Nothing`, according to the data type definition for `Maybe`,

```
data Maybe a  =  Nothing
              |  Just a
```

Conceptually, `Maybe Int` is the same as `Either () Int` -- it does represent *maybe an `Int` or nothing*, *`()`*:

```
data Either a b  =  Left a
                 |  Right b
```

so `Just i` is just like `Right i`, and `Nothing` is like `Left ()`.

But not `i` or `()` on their own -- they must be *tagged* with the appropriate data constructor, here `Right` or `Left`.